# Overflow check does not work

Tags: c#, .net

I have  following code that has a multiplication of a number with 60000 to convert minutes to milliseconds. I have implemented a overflow check as shown below. Still I am getting the following code analysis warring. How to overcome this warning without suppressing it?

> Warning: CA2233: Correct the potential overflow in the operation 'sessionExpiryValueInMinutes*60' in 'ApplicationSessionDAL.IsSessionExpired(short)'

Note: [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) is of `double` datatype

**CODE**

```
    public void IsSessionExpired(Int16 sessionExpiryValueInMinutes)
    {

        if (sessionExpiryValueInMinutes > (double.MaxValue) / 60000)
        {
            //Overflow check
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sessionExpiryValueInMinutes");
        }
        else
        {
            //int milliSecondsValue  = sessionExpiryValueInMinutes * 60 * 1000;

            DateTime lastAccessTime = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
            TimeSpan elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - lastAccessTime);
            if (elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds > (sessionExpiryValueInMinutes * 60 * 1000))
            {
                bool isTimeExpired = true;
            }

        }

    }
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [Why is FxCop warning about an overflow (CA2233) in this C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642193/why-is-fxcop-warning-about-an-overflow-ca2233-in-this-c-sharp-code)

Comment: FXCop can't tell that you have checked for the overflow. It isn't _that_ smart.

Comment: @Oded Certain times it works, for example, while addition. When we specify the range check it stop complaining the warning. I am looking for such a solution

Comment: Should you be checking Int16.MaxValue instead of double.MaxValue?

Comment: @KevinBrydon As I given in the question, TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds Property is of `double` datatype.

Comment: FYI I'm not getting any warning for that code with all Code Analysis warnings turned on (CA2233 in particular) with Visual Studio 2012 with VS2012 Update 1 installed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `Int16`? Just use `Int32/int` and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may wrap your computation in a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182354.aspx) block. That way, the program will explicitly throw a `System.OverflowException` which you can here catch to do what you want. And since you want to throw an exception anyway, in your particular case, you don't need to do anything else.

Example:

```
checked 
{
    if (elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds > (sessionExpiryValueInMinutes * 60 * 1000))
    {
        bool isTimeExpired = true;
    }
}
```

And @Oded is right, FxCop cannot be always that smart.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I suspect that it means that the result of (sessionExpiryValueInMinutes * 60 * 1000) will never hold into an Int16.

I see another issue with your code: I'm almost certain that sessionExpiryValueInMinutes, being an Int16, will never ever be greater than (double.MaxValue)/60000.